# Easiest way to embed a piece of Python code in C# (Simpler than IronPython)

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

Basically I want to make a C#.NET application but also create full Python modules that can be called from C#. I was going with IronPython but I found out that I can't add libraries like BeautifulSoup to IronPython.

I guess what I'm looking to do is embed pure python into C# rather than using IronPython which is a limited implementation of Python

Comment: You can use other libraries with IronPython; whether they work 100% is a different story. In your case, you could try html5lib instead of BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend against this type of cross-language development. It is possible, but it winds up being hackish, hard to deploy, etc.

Replace your Python libraries with C# libraries, and replace your Python code with C# code. For example, replace BeautifulSoup with [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Why the downvote? Ok yes you can do something like write real python code and simply call the external python code with [Process.Start("python code.py")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx). But then you have all sorts of issues with interprocess communication. Writing inline interpreted python is not possible.